# Importing android.net MailTo class into existing (Mule) java project

Tags: java, android, jar, mule, mule-studio

I have a Mule project (created with Mule Studio, a flavor of Eclipse.) I would like to use the android.net MailTo class, which requires a few other files within the package, such as a ParseException and URI class. I could add the files into its own package in my project, however I've read I could import the package as a jar file. I can't find the jar file anywhere, and was wondering if there's a way to create a jar file out of only a portion of the package (without classes I don't need.)
Where can I find a copy of android.net as either source or JAR file? And if I get only the source, how can I compile into a JAR file?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where can I find a copy of android.net as either source or JAR file?

There is no JAR file, strictly speaking, except as part of a firmware build.

The Android source code is available [online](http://source.android.com), including the Java classes that are part of [the `android.net` package](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/net).

However, getting this code to work on standard Java may be painful. I would recommend finding existing ordinary Java code.